# PFObject subclass, unrecognized selector sent to instance for custom method

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-framework

I have a PFObject Subclass SomeClass, to which i added a method `iconImageName`

.h

```
@interface SomeClass : PFObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary * availableAttributes;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * type;

- (NSString *)iconImageName;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation SomeClass

@dynamic availableAttributes;
@dynamic type;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}

- (NSString *)iconImageName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon-type-%@", self.type];
}

@end
```

but after calling

`[object iconImageName]` i get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject iconImageName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174133b00'
```

i can confirm that the object is indeed SomeClass

this also happens when i use a class method +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses) you ignored some subclassing rules:

> To create a `PFObject` subclass:
>   1. Declare a subclass which conforms to the `PFSubclassing` protocol.
>   2. Implement the class method `parseClassName`. This is the string you would pass to `initWithClassName:` and makes all future class name
>   references unnecessary.
>   3. Import `PFObject+Subclass` in your .m file. This implements all methods in `PFSubclassing` beyond `parseClassName`.
>   4. Call `[YourClass registerSubclass]` before Parse `setApplicationId:clientKey:`.

Try to satisfy this rules for your class.

Example:

```
// Armor.h
@interface Armor : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@end

// Armor.m
// Import this header to let Armor know that PFObject privately provides most
// of the methods for PFSubclassing.
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation Armor
+ (void)load {
  [self registerSubclass];
}

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
  return @"Armor";
}
@end
```

Comment: Sneaky Parse, I totally missed the [className registerSubclass] thing.  @PeterLapisu, you're saying you were able to put that inside the subclass' implementation, though? Calling self? The instructions there say that it has to be done before you initialize Parse, but I can see that being false / outdated.